# Extracting year from datetime datatypes is giving output as float

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm a newbee in Pandas. I need your support in a problem i'm facing
I have a datatime column in a dataframe and I'm trying to extract the year from it but the output it is giving is in float?

```
fifa['Joined_date'].head()
0   1970-01-01
1   1970-01-01
2   1970-01-01
3   1970-01-01
4   1970-01-01
Name: Joined_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

fifa['Joined_date'].dt.year
0        1970.0
1        1970.0
2        1970.0
3        1970.0
4        1970.0
Name: Joined, Length: 18207, dtype: float64

Output Expected is --> 1970
```

Can you please help?

Comment: I guess some value in your `Joined_date` column is probably `NaT`(Not a time). That's why you are facing this issue.

Comment: @VVS let me know if given answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways but below are 2 may help you

this will apply on entire frame

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
```

this is for the column

```
df['your column'] = df['your column'].astype(int)
```

if your column has mixed type of data

```
 df['your column'] = df['your column'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

Some cases you may have to convert the columns first to str and then again to int

Comment: `.astype(int)` would still raise an error since 'NaT' cannot be converted