# Convert float dtype dataframe to string dtype dataframe (NaN becomes '0')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Here is my code:

```
    dfFact = pd.read_sql_query("select * from MusicFact;", conn)
    dfFact['artist'].fillna(0)
    dfFact['artist'].astype('Int64')
    dfFact['artist'] = dfFact['artist'].astype(str)
```

[I am trying to convert the following dataframe into a string dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx5Nl.png)

But my desired output needs to be for example in this case '3','3','3','3','2','1','0','0'

I am stuck so I thought I'd come to stack - thank you in advance!

Comment: check if this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62101429/extracting-year-from-datetime-datatypes-is-giving-output-as-float/62106345?noredirect=1#comment109870660_62106345

Comment: @HietshKumar thank you for the response, my error arises when 0.0 converts to nan or <NA> when I need it to become a string '0'

Answer (score 0):

[`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) if used without `inplace=True` returns a new series with missing values filled with the replacement value. Similarly [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) returns a copy of casted series. In your case you are not assigning the results of these operations back the the series hence the changes are not propogating in the output.

Simply, use:

```
dfFact['artist'] = dfFact['artist'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
```